# Add a new file in Intellij doesn't add to subversion

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea, version-control

I'm not sure what I did to cause this, but adding a new file or package in IntelliJ now doesn't add them to subversion, and I have to add them manually via right-click -> subverion -> add.

Is there a setting that controls this behaviour?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Go to **File -> Settings -> Version control -> Confirmation -> When files are created** You're probably looking for "*Add silently*".

Note:
In IntelliJ 6 or earlier versions this is done with **File -> Settings -> Version control -> General Settings -> Add silently**

Comment: any idea on how to do this for files which are created in the project directory by an external tool?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284532/intellij-auto-add-files-to-svn) if you are still experiencing problems.

Answer (score 6):

If you've come here and the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817452/add-a-new-file-in-intellij-doesnt-add-to-subversion/2817668#2817668) by [Bozhidar Batsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291550/bozhidar-batsov) doesn't solve the issue you may need to change the svn:global-ingnores in SVN Properties for the project.

Right click on the project go to **Subversion | Set Property...**. In the drop down select **svn:global-ingores**. Remove * from the list and hit **OK**.

[image: SVN Properties: Set Property]

[image: SVN Properties: Property Element to Delete]

Comment: You sir, a life saver.

Answer (score 3):

*Simple **Shortcut key** does the work:*

Select all the unversioned files that you wish to add in SVN  and    **`CTRL + ALT + A`**

Answer (score 0):

You can check unversioned files under **View -> Changes -> Unversioned files** and add it manually to VCS (works for IntelliJ 13).

Answer (score 0):

you can go to settings, **ctrl+alt+s -> version control -> confirmation** : change the options of "**when files are created**".

also if it doesn't solved the issue you can right click on your project in intellij, go to **subvertion> edit properties**. check if there is a property named "**ignore" or "global-ignores**" with **"*"** value, remove **"*"** in these properties.