# Intellij Auto ADD Files to SVN

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

My Intellij Version 14.0.1 (x64, Java 1.8.0_25) isn´t adding files to SVN automatically.

I´m using SVN version 1.8 and already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817452/add-a-new-file-in-intellij-doesnt-add-to-subversion) approach, without success.

Does anybody knows what should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I realized what was causing this problem:

My project has a SVN Property, called `svn:global-ignores` set as bellow:

[image]

After removing the 'asterisk', everything worked fine!