# Can Intellij Idea automatically stage changes

Tags: git, intellij-idea

After a couple of days working on the task I decided to take a look at what's been done with `git status` from Git Bash.

Some files are in `Changes to be committed list`, some are in `Changes not staged for commit`. Interesting thing is, I've never added anything explicitly to the staging area. Never! How is that possible that some of the files ended up there?

Apart from just coding I did `git pull` once and `git stash/stash pop`. That's it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you "add" new files in the intellij project? If so, did they immediately turn red, or green? since in the later case there is a setting which automatically adds newly created files to VCS.

Comment: I did add 1 new file. But it's the only one I don't have questions about, because it appears in both sections: in staged as a "new file" and in unstaged because I edited it after the initial creation. All other files are the old ones.

Answer (score 10):

You may have enabled/disabled the version control `silently` mode in IDEA:

```
File -> Settings -> Version control -> Confirmation
```

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817668/435605).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The Git integration in IntelliJ IDEA stages files when the "Add" action is performed. Normally this happens when a new file is added to Git, but you can also invoke "Add" on an existing file, in which case its current contents will be staged.

Comment: What about changes to already added files? I want to skip the `git add .` phase by clicking `commit` in the GUI