# How not to stage renamed files automatically

Tags: intellij-idea, file-rename, git-stage

When I rename a class, which rename files, in intellij it automatically stage the renamed files in git.

I'd like that intellij stop doing that. Does anyone know if and how to change this automatic behavior?

*Note:*

I've got intellij configure such that when I create a new file it asks if it should add it to git. Such as described here: [Can Intellij Idea automatically stage changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488053/can-intellij-idea-automatically-stage-changes)

But when renaming a class/file it doesn't ask anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Intellij Idea automatically stage changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488053/can-intellij-idea-automatically-stage-changes)

Comment: My question is more specific: on file renaming. Moreover the answer are for adding new file. And actually, I have all the confirmation set on "show options before..."  and "Ask" (no silently selected).