# How to automatically stage all Intellj Idea files?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-stage

I'm not sure why, and I may have disabled this by default by accident, but whenever I create a new file, it appears in 'red' since it is not staged on Intellij. How do I automatically stage the files instead of going into Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntelliJ Go to the location File -> Settings -> Version control -> Confirmation -> Select "Add silently". Just as in the below screenshot:

[image]

For more info please refer thread [Add a new file in Intellij doesn't add to subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817452/add-a-new-file-in-intellij-doesnt-add-to-subversion/2817668#2817668).